# Why can't my function access a variable in an enclosing function?

Tags: python, scope

I know about the LEGB rule. But a simple test of whether a function has read access to variables defined in an enclosing function doesn't seem to actually work. Ie:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.4
'''Simple test of Python scoping rules'''

def myfunction():
    print 'Hope this works: '+myvariable

def enclosing():
    myvariable = 'ooh this worked'
    myfunction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    enclosing()
```

Returns:

```
NameError: global name 'myvariable' is not defined
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there more to it than the LEGB resolution order?

Comment: Just naming a function `enclosing` doesn't make it so :)

Comment: Yep. I'd incorrectly thought 'enclosing' included calling functions, but it actually specifically means the parents of nested functions.

Comment: there's no need to revert valid tags. It is not about you, it is about the question.

Comment: @SilentGhost I thought the specifics of a particular scoping situation are a non-beginner topic. But to avoid an edit war: if you think so, sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can...

if you did it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.4
'''Simple test of Python scoping rules'''

def enclosing():
    myvariable = 'ooh this worked'

    def myfunction():
         print 'Hope this works: ' + myvariable

    myfunction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    enclosing()
```

...otherwise your function doesn't know where to look (well it does, but it looks at the global variables, which is why you are getting the error you are getting) (pass it as a parameter if you can't define the function as a **nested** function)

Comment: (and if you want to *share* a variable you could add the "global" keyword to both functions so that they share a global variable, but I would **strongly** advise against doing anything like that unless absolutely necessary)

Comment: (i.e. "global myvariable" to the beginning of both functions)

Comment: Thanks Terence. It seems I'd incorrectly assumed that calling functions were considered to be 'enclosing', but the term specifically means the parent of a nested function.

Comment: no worries ;) ...just happened to be flipping to SO, so I figured I'd help